# Unable to import pom.xml in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I am trying to import a maven project into eclipse. But for some reason unable to import pom.xml(all other modules get imported properly).

The way I am doing it is by selecting the 'Existing maven project as an option'.
I tried by deleting the complete project and importing again but pom.xml doesn't get included in it.

Also can a pom.xml be imported separately?

Comment: by importing pom you mean the root project? the directory which contains modules and the aggregator pom.xml file?

Comment: Yes I do select the root folder when importing

Comment: to import its modules, indeed you need to select the root folder, but to import the root folder (providing the pom file) you need to select the workspace which contains the root folder, then select the root folder from that view (it will be recognized as maven project)